# Laptop using 14.04 won't get past login GUI

Tags: login, lightdm

My laptop was working perfectly yesterday, and now today I can't log in.

At first, I was only getting a black screen. However, after following instructions in some questions here on **AskUbuntu**, I first reinstalled `lightdm`, and then I had to change the ownership of the file `~/.Xauthority` to be my user name. Now, I get the log in GUI screen.

However, once I enter my username, it flickers and then comes back to the login GUI. It does not matter if I use *Gnome*, *Unity*, or *Gnome-Flashback*.

I don't know why `lightdm` needed to be reconfigured, or how `~/.Xauthority` got changed, but in any case, what is still standing in my way, preventing me from logging in?

**Update:** I have tried deleting the `.Xauthority` file, and the `.profile` files in my home directory. It has not changed anything.

Logging in as guest also fails to work.

The following commands did not work:

```
mv ~/.config ~/.config.BAK
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.BAK
```

Inside `.xsession-errors` in my home directory, it says:

```
Gdk-CRITICAL: gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.Xauthority` file then rebooting?

Comment: @Cornelius, thank you for responding. Unfortunately, deleting `.Xauthority` did not fix the problem.

Comment: how did you know that the repository updated those 4 package ?? I ve the same problem but it triggered when i installed virtualbox form a .deb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my issue.
I had this repository

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu trusty main`

in my list. That repository yesterday updated these 4 packages to a custom version (based on GNOME 3.12):

- ubuntu-session
- gnome-session-common
- gnome-session-bin
- gnome-session

I downgraded these packages to the version `3.9.90-0ubuntu12` and after a `sudo service lightdm restart` all is working, up and running.

To downgrade from command line:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-bin=3.9.90-0ubuntu12
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-common=3.9.90-0ubuntu12
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session=3.9.90-0ubuntu12
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session=3.9.90-0ubuntu12
```

Comment: Sounds good. Can you be more descriptive in *how* exactly you did that? How does one downgrade these packages from the commandline?

Comment: I added the command on the answer :)

Comment: Great work! I have my laptop back. Also, welcome to AskUbuntu! `:)`

Comment: What's special about this PPA? And why should I trust it?

Comment: @Cerin I don't remember why I used this PPA, but the downgrade instructions brings the official Ubuntu packages back

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too after updating. I had to reinstall the display driver to get it to work. The computer that had this problem has an nVidia card running nVidia's driver.

Answer (score 1):

I my case I replace lightdm to  GDM Worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Select the display manager GDM