# How do I prevent software packages from being downloaded until I know it's safe?

Tags: apt, upgrade

Recently, an [update that caused a problem with Gnome session](https://askubuntu.com/q/481680/17041) caused me to lose a day's work. The solution was to rollback some packages to a previous version.

The update manager is now telling me that my old packages should be updated:

[image: updating packages I don't want to update]

... but I don't want to do that until I know that whatever bug or problem the latest version has is resolved.

I understand that with any upgrade that there is a risk of instability. However, in the 8 years or more that I've been on Ubuntu, using the latest releases has been stable enough and with the benefit of the latest features and security. So, **I'm not looking for general advice on how to handle upgrades**.

What I'm saying is that in this one particular instance, the bug introduced by these upgrades is severe and time wasting. But, as an end user, when I encounter a problem like this, I have no idea how to address a specific concern about a specific package. I don't, for example, know which of these packages is the problem, and I can't take time from my work schedule to be experimenting with each package.

So, my question is:

How do I find out who exactly is responsible for these, or any, packages so that I can contact them and let them know about the problem?

How do I freeze these packages only, but allow other upgrades to happen?

```
ubuntu-session
gnome-session-common
gnome-session-bin
gnome-session
```

Comment: Ask the author of the PPA whether the bug is fixed? But in general any new versions of packages could introduce some new bugs. The easiest way to roll back a system is to use btrfs and apt-btrfs-snapshot. The hard way is to manually revert all the package versions.

Comment: @bain, thanks for responding. I'm aware that new versions of anything could have bugs, but over the years it's been safe enough to largely allow upgrades. However, in this one case, the bug halted me working or using my computer entirely, so I'm only seeking caution in this one instance, because the process of recovery is quite painful. I tried seeing [where to report a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~eugenesan) on the package, but it certainly isn't obvious or easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent package to be udated by *freezing* them.

You do this like this :

```
echo "<package name> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can see the list of *frozen* package by doing this :

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep hold
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said in the comments, you can never know when it's "safe" to update packages. Introducing new software ALWAYS has the possibility of ruining your environment.

This is why IT departments in companies use test environments and try out updates on similar machines before deploying them to their production machines (at least, any self-respecting admin would do so). You can use virtual machines as well, but that doesn't necessarily allow you to test anything related to the hardware or gui (i.e. your gnome problem), just core services.

If you don't have the luxury of a test environment, you can be a little more sure about the updates if you don't enable automatic updates (or checking for updates), and manually check if there are updates available and browse the web to see if there are any bugs reported with the updates. In that case, always lag a couple days/weeks behind the updates (unless there's a huge security risk).
My personal experience though, is that software these days is tested as good as possible before it's rolled out, and if you want to take the manual way of checking everything before installing, you'll be spending A LOT more time than you would on the occasional hiccup. And indeed, if you have experienced problems, if you want to protect yourself from doing a days work to recover, you should install some snapshot technology (e.g. btrfs) which allows you to revert quickly.

So everything in a nutshell, there is no answer to your request, only guidelines on how to deal with reality. You have to make up your own mind to see what works best for you.