# Keyboard shortcuts for switching language input method no longer works after updates

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

As part of a string of problems with recent updates in Gnome Flashback (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/488849/17041), and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/481680/17041)), after an update a day or so ago, the shortcut keys I have assigned for switching between Japanese and English stopped working.

I use iBus and Anthy on Gnome Flashback. I have set the shortcut keys to be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, but it doesn't respond at all. I have tried changing the keys in the "Text Entry Settings..." interface, but it doesn't seem to matter what keys I opt to use.

I can still switch input methods by clicking on the applet icon in the gnome panel and selecting from the options that drop down, but when typing a lot and switching constantly, as I am almost always doing, having to do it that way really sucks.

How do I get the shortcut keys for switching input methods to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noticing from your previous questions:

- [How do I get my Compiz window decoractions back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497066/how-do-i-get-my-compiz-window-decoractions-back)
- [Laptop using 14.04 won't get past login GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481680/laptop-using-14-04-wont-get-past-login-gui)

That you are using `ppa:eugenesan/ppa` (same as me) which has couple of inconsistent package builds with higher versions then the ones in Ubuntu repository.

As it seems bringing many issues for you. Better to disable/remove it and purge installed packages from it and reinstall them from Ubuntu repo. I case you need specific app from it, make only selective upgrade/install from it, avoid blind upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the new shortcuts are <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. To change them, go to the *Input Sources* section of the *Region and Language* settings.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I think you may have misunderstood the problem. As mentioned in the question, I have tried setting the shortcut keys to various things, and the changes do not take effect no matter what keys I select, even `super+space`.